# Shared project between two solutions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, blazor

I have a shared project between two solutions. Working in the first solution (server) I have added new files to the Entities project, and now I am trying to reload the Entities project in the second solution (client), but it is not working - new files do not appear.

[image: Structure of my solutions]
[image: Folders structures]

Comment: How do you share the code? If this the identical project directory on the hard disk? You might also consider putting Server and Client into the same solution.

Comment: Either put all of them in one Solution as Klaus said, or make the shared library a separate nuget that you put on a [corporate or project feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview) and restore in both projects.

Comment: It works fine on Visual Studio 2019. Try to unload the project and check you have the new files saved in .csproj correctly. new files/folder should appear under <ItemGroup><Compile Include="..." /> </ItemGroup>

Comment: Is it _the same_ "Entities" Project or is it two projects, that happen to have the same name and (before the new files) same content?

Comment: Which version of VS are you using ? Assuming you mean it is the exact same project on disk, I have no such problem on VS2022 - when I change a shared project in one solution the other solution using this project is automatically updated.

Comment: I have added a picture of the file structure. Yes it is on one disk. I would like to have this as two separate solutions @KlausGütter.

Comment: It's hard to actually understand the file structure with only screenshots. Can you run this powershell command `cd <pathofyourproject>` then `gci -Recurse | select fullname` and show the result? (not as screenshot, but as text please)

Comment: I have tried and it does not work @Behnam

Comment: Also VS2022 @wohlstad

Comment: I have now tried deleting and adding back new files to this shared project and it works. It seems to me that this problem arose from version control system

Comment: I am very glad that your work has progressed. We often encounter the problem of old file conflicts when we integrate projects. At this time, we usually need to delete the old files. But you need to be cautious when doing this.